# How to list the most popular content for different periods of time with Radioactivity?

Tags: 7, views, rules

I'd like to create a view with the most popular content of the last week, the last month and of all time. I've installed the [Radioactivity](https://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module and created the three required profiles. While adding a radioactivity field 'Popularity' to my nodes, I had to select one of these three profiles, so I assume that I'll have to add another two radioactivity fields with the other profiles and that I'll end up with three fields

- 'Popularity (week)'
- 'Popularity (month)'
- 'Popularity (all time)'.

Is that correct? If yes, I'm wondering whether I now have to create the same rules for the three fields every time in order to change their value. Isn't it possible to add an action that adds an incident to the three fields at the same time, as the incident-values will be the same in the three cases?

This repetition is not a very big problem, but I'm not sure whether the set-up for what I want to achieve is completely correct, because doing the same work multiple times in Drupal is wrong most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.  There is a one-to-one relationship between fields and profiles.  Since one field cannot represent multiple profiles, you will need 3 fields.

In answer to your Rules question, it should be possible to create a rule with 3 actions to update the 3 fields at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's good to read that someone finally confirms my approach.